# IBM Websphere JPA configuration - how to update persistence.xml

Tags: java, orm, jpa, websphere, openjpa

I'm new to EJB 3 and the JPA.

I've created a datasource in the appserver which is `jdbc/AppDataSource`. The default persistence provider is left as `com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl`.
And I left the default jta data source JNDI name as `AppDataSource` itself.
I'm actually confused regarding JTA and non-JTA. What differentiates them?

I generated the entities and created an `EntityTransaction` object in the bean.
Upon calling the `persist()` and `commit()` methods, I get an error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
```

How does openjpa comes into picture here?

As of now, my `persistence.xml` contains the entity class names only.

How can I make it use the default appserver values for data source. Or else how can I provide the details of jpa provider and datasource details in the `persistence.xml`?

Please provide your inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question actually involves many concepts and I won't cover them all in details. For more exhaustive details, I suggest reading the whole **Chapter 5 - Entity Managers and Persistence Contexts** of the JPA 1.0 specification (and the other relevant sections mentioned at the end of this answer). I will rather try to describe the most common scenario in a Java EE environment.

Within an EJB environment, one would typically use:

- A *container-managed entity manager* (must be a JTA entity manager)

  - *transaction-scoped* in Stateless Session Beans (SLSB)
  - *extended* in Stateful Session Beans (SFSB)
- JTA Transaction Management (and not *resource-local transactions* unless this is **really** what you want)

Here is how a `persistence.xml` for a JTA entity manager that uses a data source with a JNDI name `java:comp/env/jdbc/AppDataSource` can be set up, OpenJPA being the persistence provider used by WebSphere:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/AppDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.acme.domain.Foo</class>
    <class>com.acme.domain.Bar</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <!-- OpenJPA specific properties -->
      <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

For the OpenJPA properties, refer to the OpenJPA [documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.1/apache-openjpa-1.2.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_conf_openjpa.html#openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode).

And here is how a SLSB (using Container Managed Transactions) could get a container managed Entity Manager injected:

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeServiceBean implements EmployeeService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MyPu")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Employee createEmployee(int id, String name, long salary) {
        Employee emp = new Employee(id);
        emp.setName(name);
        emp.setSalary(salary);
        em.persist(emp);
        return emp;
    }
    ...    
}
```

And that's all. The life cycle of the entity manager is managed by the container transparently for the application (no createEM/close) and the entity manager participates in the JTA transaction managed by the container (no explicit begin/commit).

As previously hinted, I'm just scratching the surface, my goal is somehow to put you on the right path. To go further, I suggest grabbing a book (e.g. EJB3 in Action). Meanwhile, the references below would be a good reading.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 5.2.1 "Obtaining an Entity Manager in the Java EE Environment"
  - Section 5.5 "Controlling Transactions"
  - Section 5.6 "Container-managed Persistence Contexts"
  - Section 6.2.1.2 "transaction-type"
  - Section 6.2.1.4 "provider"
  - Section 6.2.1.5 "jta-data-source, non-jta-data-source"

#### Resources

- [Leveraging OpenJPA with WebSphere Application Server V6.1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_barcia/0612_barcia.html)

Comment: Really really helpful! I updated my persistence.xml and included the JTA datasource and I'm reading the documentation of openjpa and EJB specs too...

Comment: @whoopy Glad it was helpful (it's not an topic easy to summarize).

Comment: @Pascal: I tried what you have mentioned above, but i am still getting the same error. My database is MS SQL Server, hence I replaced db2 with sqlserver in `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2"/>` Can you please help me?