# Datasource configuration for stand alone application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere, jpa-2.0, datasource

I have creatd the data source in Websphere spplication server. But I want to use this in my JPA project. I have created the JPA project in Websphere environment. I have used the bellow way to use the data source. But it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DSDemo">

        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.nyl.ltc.auditlog.model.AuditLog</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="openjpa.connection.datasource" value="oracleDS" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="SMSCSRVC" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error**

```
<openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1087028 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1087028 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" and URL "null".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
```

Note: The Datasource was created and tested the connection. It was success. I use OpenJPA as a JPA provider.

Please let me know where I went wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Websphere. Is your datasource an jta-data-source? If so, try mapping as one using it's JNDI binding. Refer to topic 2.1 of this http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_dbsetup_thirdparty.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case you already have a Datasource created in WAS you don't actually need to use OpenJPA datasource anymore(All DB specific information is already on WebSphere).

All you need to do is to get the DS reference and than get the connection:

I believe this thread will have the information you need: [IBM Websphere JPA configuration - how to update persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526434/ibm-websphere-jpa-configuration-how-to-update-persistence-xml)

If not, check OpenJPA documentation about this at: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-1.0.3/docs/manual/ref_guide_dbsetup_sqlconn.html

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.1/apache-openjpa-1.2.1/docs/javadoc/org/apache/openjpa/persistence/OpenJPAPersistence.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_barcia/0612_barcia.html